# Why I see the class name tooltip when I define a style for the tooltips?

Tags: wpf

I have created a style for a tooltip. This is the style:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipDefaultStyle">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="{StaticResource TooltipInitialShowDelay}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="{StaticResource TooltipDisplayTime}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}" TextWrapping='Wrap'
                               Margin="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is I use it in a control:

```
<StackPanel ToolTip="{Binding MyViewModelProperty}">
    
    ..........

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToolTipDefaultStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is that tooltip, at the start, it shows this text: "System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip". After that, it shows the text I want to show.

How could avoid to show this first text?

What I want to have is a style for all the controls of the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolTip` control is a `ContentControl`. The `ContentTemplate`'s `DataContext` will be the `Content` property.

So you just need to change your `TextBlock` binding to:

```xml
<TextBlock
    Margin="10"
    Text="{Binding}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of problems in your code.

Firstly if You want to use this ToolTip style for all Tooltips in the application, You should define it without x:key.

Secondly, You got this "System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip", because Your binding is not correct, You should specify the Path for that binding.

Here's corrected Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="500"/>
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="1500"/>
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Width="50"
                           Margin="10"
                           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}, Path=Content}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

If You define the Style correctly, there's no need for that StackPanel.Resources, just provide content for the ToolTip

```
<StackPanel Margin="100"
            Background="Red"
            ToolTip="This is Tooltip"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works, but it is simplier the accepted answer, because it just set Binding instead o set the ancestor. But this is another solution that works. Thanks.